# Grabbing all image urls from a page using curl (looping)

Tags: php, regex, loops, curl

I have created a simple script to grab image URLs from a page. The script does this but only grabs the first URL, some direction on how to loop this would be appreciated.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>RUscraper</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="get">
  MemberID: 
  <input type="text" name="memberIDsubmit" />
  <input type="submit" value="Scrape" />
 </form>
 <?php
  if ($_GET["memberIDsubmit"]) {
   
   function scrape() {
    $memberID = $_GET["memberIDsubmit"];
    echo $memberID;

    $curl = curl_init("http://domain.com/profile/?Id=$memberID");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $page = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl); 

    $regex = "/https?:\/\/[^ ]+?(?:\.jpg)/";
    preg_match($regex, $page, $output);   

       echo "<pre>";
       var_dump($output);
       echo $page;
       echo "</pre>";
      } 

      scrape();
  }
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to perform a global search. Matches will be in `$output[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use wget with the -p option instead of curl to get the page and all of its elements (such as images, css files, javascript files, etc):

```
wget -p http://www.example.com/path/to/page.html
```